# XOR operator with grep when we grep on 2 patterns

Tags: grep, pattern-matching, xor

I am using grep to find match of 2 patterns with condition OR like this, classically:

```
grep -E 'C_matrix|F_matrix' triplot_XC_dev_for_right_order_with_FoM.py | wc -l
```

I would like now to exclude the cases when both pattern are matched on the same line, i.e I would like to use a XOR operator with grep.

How can I do this operation ? Maybe another trick is possible (I think about `grep -v` to exclude but this would be nice to do this operation in ony one command line with `grep -E`).

Comment: `grep -P '^(?!.*F_matrix).*C_matrix|^(?!.*C_matrix).*F_matrix)'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you want to make such a special case, it is better to make use of `awk`:

```
 $ awk '(/C_matrix/ && !/F_matrix/) || (!/C_matrix/ && !/F_matrix/)' file
```

Using GNU awk, you can use the bit-manipulation function `xor`:

```
$ awk 'xor(/C_matrix/,/F_matrix/)' file
```